# Forge Viewer Autodesk v7 issues with recolouring THREE.BufferGeoemtry when using THREE.ShaderMaterial

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-bim360

EDIT: The Forge Viewer I'm using has customized version of Three.js release r71 (source) which is why I'm using outdated code. The current release of Three.js is r121.

I've created THREE.Group() that contains various THREE.Pointcloud(geometry, material). One of the Points is composed of THREE.BufferGeometry() and THREE.ShaderMaterial().

When I add a colour attribute to a BufferGeometry, only only red (1,0,0), white (1,1,1), or yellow (1,1,0) seem to work. This [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bk74K.png) is when I set the colour to (1,0,0). This [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXyXS.png) is when I set the colour to blue (0,0,1).

My question is, how do I resolve this? Is the issue in the shaders? Is the issue with how I build the BufferGeometry? Is it a bug? Thanks.

My shaders:

```
var vShader = `uniform float size;
        varying vec3 vColor;
        void main() {
            vColor = color;
            vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
            gl_PointSize = size * ( size / (length(mvPosition.xyz) + 0.00001) );
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
        }`
        var fShader = `varying vec3 vColor;
        uniform sampler2D sprite;
        void main() {
            gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor, 1.0 ) * texture2D( sprite, gl_PointCoord );
            if (gl_FragColor.x < 0.2) discard;
        }`
```

My material:

```
var materialForBuffers = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
            uniforms: {
                size: { type: 'f', value: this.pointSize},
                sprite: { type: 't', value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("../data/white.png") },
            },
            vertexShader: vShader,
            fragmentShader: fShader,
            transparent: true,
            vertexColors: true,
        });
```

How the color is added:

```
const colors = new Float32Array( [ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 ] );
                geometryForBuffers.addAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute( colors, 3 ));
```

[Link to code](https://github.com/SimulationEverywhere-Models/COVID-BIM/blob/Visualization_ParticleJS/public/js/particles.js)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may already be using parts of that sample code but if not, please refer to https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-point-clouds/blob/develop/public/scripts/extensions/pointcloud.js (live demo https://forge-point-clouds.autodesk.io). This sample code uses the `color` geometry attribute already to specify colors of individual points.